# Weird thing when using css module in React project

Tags: reactjs

I don't want to bother you but it's so weird so I did post about this.
If my question is stupid, hope your understanding. 
I tried to style a component with a css module.

```
// style.css
.textarea {
 color: red;
}
// app.js
...
import styles from './style.css'
console.log(styles)
...
<textarea style = {styles.textarea}></textarea>
...
```

The output is []. I tried the same thing a few hours ago but it worked well.
I have no idea about this and really don't understand why it is.
Why is not "style.css" recognized?

Comment: How are you processing your CSS file(s)?

Comment: I just created style.css file and the content is above.

Comment: are you sure you've placed `style.css` in the same folder as react component? rename it to something different. I bet you have an empty `style.css` in that folder.

Comment: I already tried. I guessed so. So I changed the name of the css file and imported as new name but it was also failed. I created new file and tried again but it was also failed. I am sure it's on the same level.

Comment: Try to apply it through `className` like `<textarea className = "textarea"></textarea>`

Comment: I already tried with className. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Only style objects can be used if they are Stylesheet objects:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textarea: {
    color: 'red'
  }
});
```

usage:

```
<textarea style = {styles.textarea}></textarea>
```

or use the class from the imported stylesheet:

```
.textarea {
 color: red;
}
```

```
<textarea className ='textarea'></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But It seems like css-js way to style. I wanted to use css module. Besides, It worked for a previous small task. Look at this https://github.com/stevenkimmach/new_films  It works well.

Comment: But they use the class names too? https://github.com/stevenkimmach/new_films/blob/master/src/Movie.js#L14 @StevenKim

Answer (score -1):

If you are using create react app you should try this:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet

Comment: I already tried. I replaced "style" property to "className" but it also didn't work.